# how to select between multiple versions within html documentation?

Tags: doxygen

I have a doxygen generated documentation for every release version:

```
doc/1.0.0/index.html
doc/1.0.1/index.html
...
```

how can I select the version within the html documentation? As an example, note the dropdown selection box in the html header in [this example](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0).

I am not aware of such build-in feature from doxygen so I think it is a custom header.

**Question**

how can I select the version within html documentation generated by doxygen?

Comment: Doxygen does not provide such a feature. Best is to study how OpenCV did it or how it is done in https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/index.html

Comment: For CGAL have a look in Documentation/doc/resources/1.8.14/menu_version.js in their source tree and how they incorporate this in Documentation/doc/resources/1.8.14/hacks.js.

Comment: It was just by a little bit of reverse engineering and a little knowledge about CGAL documentation. For which package are you using doxygen (when you want and can share the information).